# Oracle SQL - Factor up values to achieve required total

Tags: sql, oracle, math, plsql

I am looking for a sql function/calculation that allows me to factor up a set of values to achieve a required target.

To make it clearer. I have steps to build a product. Each step takes a certain amount of time.
8.6, 7.2, 6.6, 6.6, 3.1, 5.9, 9.2, 4.5, 4.4, 2.7, 7.7, 7.7, 5.8. The total of these rows gives me 80 days to finish the build. But my manager comes along and says it now takes 125 days. How can I factor up each step so that the new total gives me 125 days?

Excel can achieve this using goal seek. I can not find a similar function in SQL or PLSQL.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*,
       t.time * (125 / sum(t.time) over (partition by product)) as scaled_time
from t;
```

This scales up each value so the sum will be `125`.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much.